# Assembly nasm; how to access front and end of string

Tags: string, assembly, nasm

I am trying to convert input string '_Haris_I_' into 'Haris_I'. So I am trying to remove the underscore from the front and end of the string. I have already defined input and buffer pointers in memory and they store the char pointer to string '_Haris_I_'. This is the code I am using to do this, but it seems to not work for the front of the string:

```
 ;;test front of buffer

         mov al, buffer
         cmp al, 0x5f
         jne test_end

       ;; move the buffer pointer to the next character
         mov eax, buffer
         inc eax
         mov buffer, eax

     ;; test end of buffer
       test_end:   

        push dword buffer
        call _strlen
        mov dword length, eax 
        mov ebx, length
        mov eax, buffer
        mov al, [eax+ebx-1] ;; put the final char of the string into al: "_"
        cmp al, 0x5f
        jne final_exit
        mov eax, buffer
        mov dword [eax+ebx-1], 0 ;; put 0 in place of the final char of the string ;to end the string prematurely
        mov buffer, eax
        add esp, 4

        final_exit:
        ;; // printf("|%s|\n",buffer); 
;copy buffer to input for printing
         mov eax, buffer
         mov ecx, input
         push eax
         push ecx
         call _strcpy
         add esp, 8

        push eax

        ;; free(buffer); 
        call _free

        add esp, 4


    leave 
    ret
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mov eax, buffer
mov al, [eax]
```

solved the problem. The problem was that I was loading the pointer address of buffer into al, not the first byte of the buffer.

Comment: You could just do `mov al, [buffer]`.  You only need to do a mov-immediate to load an address into a reg if you want to use it repeatedly.  Or esp. to modify it (to point elsewhere in a buffer).  And of course your addresses are only immediate constants when you're using static/global variables, instead of scratch space on the stack, from malloc, or from a function parameter.